# add class with check_box in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {checked: (@employee.is_active ? false : true) }, 0, 1) %>
```

but I want to add class inside this how it will be done.

I had tried it like this:

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {checked: (@employee.is_active ? false : true) }, 0, 1, :class=> 'abcd') %>
```

But it gives me error.Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {checked: (@employee.is_active ? false : true) ,:class=> 'abcd'}, 0, 1) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to put the class inside the options hash like this:

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, { checked: (@employee.is_active ? false : true), class: 'abcd' }, 0, 1) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {checked: !@employee.is_active, class: 'eula_check' }, 0, 1) %>
```